# Push Notifications Not displayed using expo go react native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

i have react native expo app and somehow the expo push notifications are not working below is my code.even though the status returned is ok and i get Ok response i still cant display notifications on my device running expo go.Below is my code . I hope someone can help me out

```
import {
      View,
      StyleSheet,
      SafeAreaView,
      Alert,
      Text,
      ActivityIndicator,
      Platform,
    } from "react-native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AboutScreen from "./AboutScreen";
import MainCategoriesScreen from "./MainCategoriesScreen";
import SingleCategoryScreen from "./SingleCategoryScreen";
import ServiceScreen from "./ServiceDetailScreen";
import ChatScreen from "./ChatScreen";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import * as Device from "expo-device";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";
import {
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useLayoutEffect,
  useContext,
  useRef,
} from "react";

import Authentication from "./Authentication";
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import { Userctx } from "../store/userContext";
import Payment from "../components/HandlePayment";
import * as NewNavigate from "../extra/NavigationService";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
    priority: "high",
  }),
});

async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;
  if (Device.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } =
      await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
      Alert.alert("You Must Enable Notifications For Updates.");
      return;
    }
    Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync;
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
    console.log(token);
  } else {
    Alert.alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
  }

  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
      name: "default",
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
    });
  }

  return token;
}

const Home = (props) => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  const [showAboutScreen, setShowAboutScreen] = useState();
  const [isConnected, setisConnected] = useState();
  const uctx = useContext(Userctx);
  const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState("");
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState(false);
  const notificationListener = useRef();
  const responseListener = useRef();
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync()
      .then((token) => {
        setExpoPushToken(token);
        return AsyncStorage.setItem("DeviceToken", token);
      })
      .then((i) => console.log("Token Done", i))
      .catch((e) => console.log("token Error", e));

    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
        setNotification(notification);
      });

    responseListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
        notificationListener.current
      );
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkInternetConnection = async () => {
      const netInfoState = await NetInfo.fetch();
      setisConnected(netInfoState.isConnected);
    };

    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      setisConnected(state.isConnected);
    });

    checkInternetConnection();

    // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
  // useLayoutEffect(() => {
  //   AsyncStorage.removeItem("aboutScreenShown", () => {
  //     console.log("removed");
  //     setShowAboutScreen(true);
  //   });
  //   AsyncStorage.removeItem("user", () => {
  //     console.log("removed user");
  //   });
  //   AsyncStorage.removeItem("DeviceToken", () => {
  //     console.log("removed token");
  //   });
  // }, []);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("user")
      .then((value) => {
        if (value === null) {
        } else {
          const data = JSON.parse(value);
          uctx.setuserInfo(data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error retrieving local storage value:", error);
      });
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Check local storage value to determine if the "About" screen has been shown before

    AsyncStorage.getItem("aboutScreenShown")
      .then((value) => {
        console.log("first Time View", value);
        if (value === null) {
          // If the value is null, it means the "About" screen has not been shown before
          setShowAboutScreen(true);
          // Update local storage value to indicate that the "About" screen has been shown
          AsyncStorage.setItem("aboutScreenShown", "true");
        } else {
          console.log("Available");
          setShowAboutScreen(false);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error retrieving local storage value:", error);
      });
  }, []);
  if (!isConnected)
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Not Connected To Internet</Text>
        <ActivityIndicator
          size={60}
          color="red"
          style={{ marginVertical: 30 }}
        />
      </View>
    );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.maincontainer}>
      {/* <NavigationContainer> */}
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={showAboutScreen ? "About" : "MainCategories"}

        // initialRouteName={"Payment"}
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="About"
          component={AboutScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="MainCategories"
          component={MainCategoriesScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SingleCategory"
          component={SingleCategoryScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: true }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SingleService"
          component={ServiceScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: true, headerTitle: "Service Details" }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ChatScreen"
          component={ChatScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: true }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Authentication"
          component={Authentication}
          options={{ headerShown: true }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Payment"
          component={Payment}
          options={{ headerShown: true }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
      {/* </NavigationContainer> */}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  maincontainer: { flex: 1 },
});
export default Home;
```

The response i get when i send a notification to my phone is

```
 {
    "response": [
        {
            "status": "ok",
            "id": "1f01cbcc-d4b1-42b6-99e6-d5ff595d46e4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it was driving me crazy. What ended up fixing it for me was following [this guide in the expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#get-credentials-for-development-builds).

So I had just been running `expo start` and testing that way etc. initially, but to get the notifications fully working, I had to:

- Go into Firebase and create an Android app for my project
- Download `google-services.json` from that and put it in the root of my project
- Run `eas build:configure` and `eas build` to build the Android app (this is okay to do even if you're still developing) which also created a Keystore (which I needed later during the next step)
- Follow the instructions in the above guide to add your Google Cloud Notifications key into the Expo Server

Finally after all that was done, notifications were finally popping up on my phone when I tested again.